# Optimizing word embedding calculation in Python

Tags: python, jupyter, spacy

I'm creating a program that calculates embeddings of word in the text of many songs from a dataset (there are almost 6k songs)

The main issue is that the calculation takes far too long.

Is there a way to speed up the process?

The code is the following:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

songs = []

for filename in os.listdir('songs'):
    df = pd.read_csv('songs/'+filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    songs.append(df)

songs = pd.concat(songs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
songs = songs.drop(columns=['Album', 'Date','Unnamed: 0'])

import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
songEmbeddings = []

for i in tqdm(range(len(songs))):
    text = nlp(songs.iloc[i]['Lyric'])
    tokens = [lemmatize_token(token) for token in text if not token.is_stop and not token.is_punct]
    wordEmbeddings = []
    for t in tokens:
        wordEmbeddings.append(nlp(t).vector)
    emb = np.mean(wordEmbeddings,0)
    songEmbeddings.append(emb)
```

I'm creating a program that calculates embeddings of word in the text of many songs from a dataset (there are almost 6k songs)

The main issue is that the calculation takes far too long.

Is there a way to speed up the process?

Comment: multiprocessing would be ideal here

Comment: The only thing you could do is multiprocessing. Everything else seems to be as it should be

Comment: @Pingu how can i do it?

Comment: It looks like you could use [pipelines](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#multiprocessing)

Comment: @roganjosh do i only have to put "nlp.pipe" instead of "nlp" function?

Comment: No idea, never used the library. It's just clear that you'd need multiprocessing so I did part of the research for you.

Comment: Can you clarify this by showing the code for * lemmatize_token* and also a fragment of one the the CSV (?) files

Comment: @Pingu `def lemmatize_token(token):
    return token.lemma_`

Comment: The CSV file is formatted as: "Artist,Title,Album,Year,Date,Lyric" where Lyric is the text of the song

Comment: Why are you dropping 'Unnamed: 0' if it's not included in the CSV?

Comment: it's a problem of the dataset, there is this column without name. But i don't think this is the problem

Comment: @xSambx02 drop() will raise an exception if you ask it to drop a non-existent column